# Create graph image in browser

Tags: javascript, browser, graph

I need to create a couple of graphs (barchart, line chart and pie chart) to insert as an image in a word file. My application is running in the browser (react).

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?
(I haven't found an answer to similar questions, to my surprise)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found an answer myself: I can use plotly to create the graph and export it to image directly (https://community.plotly.com/t/export-image-without-plotting/8507)